# SQL - select group of records that only meet certain criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out how to write a query to select a group of records that only have a certain condition that is true.  Here is an example.  I have a table that has a list of boats and the owners.  When a boat gets sold to a new owner, a new record is inserted and the CURRENTOWNER flag changes to Y:

```
OWNERID   BOATID    CURRENTOWNER
------   --------   ------------
OWN1       NUM1          Y
OWN2       NUM1          N
OWN3       NUM1          N
OWN4       NUM2          N
OWN5       NUM2          N
OWN6       NUM2          N
OWN7       NUM3          Y
```

I'm trying to write query that will show me only the BOATID's that have multiple owners (e.g. NUM1 or NUM2) and also do not have a current owner, meaning for that particular BOATID, there are no records where CURRENTOWNER = 'Y'.  From the data above, the query should return the NUM2 since it does not have a current owner.

I know I can get the list of boats that have had multiple owners using:

```
select boatid from boattable group by boatid having count(*) >1
```

After that I'm unsure how to only get the records which have no current owner.

Comment: Why do your ID's have character strings included?

Comment: @GordonLinoff apologies.  I correct the paragraph and also removed the sql-server tag as this is in Oracle.

Comment: @Zane this is just sample data, although our actual data types for these fields are varchar2.  I added the OWN and NUM prefixes for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select 
  BOATID
from 
  boattable b
where 
  not exists (
    select 1 from boattable b2
    where b2.BOATID = b.BOATID and b2.CURRENTOWNER = 'Y')
group by
  BOATID
having
  count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with conditional aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select boatid
from boattable
group by boatid
having count(*) > 1 and
       sum(case when current_owner = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This checks that there is more than one owner and non of them are current.

Note:  Given the structure of your data, you could write:

```
having count(*) > 1 and max(current_owner) = 'N'
```

However, I think the first version is clearer on the intent and less susceptible to errors if new values appear in the `current_owner` column.